# How to create many-to.many association with extra columns?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, composite-key

I'm using Hibernate and Spring Data.

I have three tables, the first with composite primary key.

```
table (grupo)
----------------
|PK idGrupo    |
|PK nombre     |
|              |
|______________|
```

Also I created 2 more tables usuario and grupo_matricula(result of the relation many to many between Grupo and usuario).

```
table (grupo_matricula)
------------------
|PK idgrupos      |
|   matricula_id  |
|   grupos_id     |
|   nombre        |
|   aceptado      |
|   propietario   |
|                 |
|_________________|

table (usuario)
----------------
|PK matricula  |
|   nombre     |
|   password   |
|______________|
```

I created 3 Clases one for entity (grupo), other for PK EmbeddedId of grupo by last for entity (grupo_matricula).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GRUPO")

public class Grupo implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    protected GrupoPK grupoPK;
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "grupo_id", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<GrupoMatricula> grupoMatriculas=new HashSet<>(0);
}


@Embeddable
public class GrupoPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "idGrupo")
    private String idGrupo;
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "grupo_matricula")
public class GrupoMatricula implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idgrupos")
    private Long idgrupos;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "idGrupo", insertable = false, updatable = false,referencedColumnName = "idGrupo"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "nombre", insertable = false, updatable = false,referencedColumnName = "nombre")
    })
    private Grupo grupo;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario", referencedColumnName = "matricula")
    private User usuario;


    @Column(name = "aceptado")
    private short aceptado;

    @Column(name = "propietario")
    private short propietario;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario") 
public class User extends  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-z0-9]*$")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 13)
    @Column(name = "matricula",length = 13, unique = true ,nullable = false)
    private String matricula;

    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 100)
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String password;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "nombre", length = 50)
    private String nombre;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usuario")
    private Set<GrupoMatricula> grupoMatriculaSet=new HashSet<>(0);
}
```

when i try run the project, it showed me error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.mx.agora.domain.GrupoMatricula.grupo_id in com.mx.agora.domain.Grupo.grupoMatriculas
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mappedBy` attribute indicates the property name that owns the relationship, not the column name. So, the proper mapping is:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "grupo", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your entity `GrupoMatricula`, your Grupo object is named `grupo`.
This is the name that mappedBy needs.

Here, you give to `mappedBy` the name of the ID in your database. I understand your error, because the attribute name in database is use on `@Column` and `@JoinColumn` annotations.

So in your `Grupo` class, you have to put:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "grupo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<GrupoMatricula> grupoMatriculas = new HashSet<>(0);
```

Instead of

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "grupo_id", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<GrupoMatricula> grupoMatriculas=new HashSet<>(0);
```

Here is a [good example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) of a use of Hibernate's `@OneToMany` if needed :)